# How to check if duplicates exist or not in solidity pure function

Tags: solidity

```
function checkDuplicates(uint[] memory array) public pure returns(bool) {
  // if array has duplicates, return false, else return true
}
```

---

It is impossible to use mapping variables within pure functions in solidity.
And not recommended to use multiple loops.
Then how I can solve it?
Hope anyone helps me with this question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't see any other reasonable approach than to just use inner loops.

You could, in theory, try some tricks like adding the seen values in a new array and sort that after each entry and for new entries loop until its slot has gone (so you know it's not in the array), but that's a horrible mess and most likely more expensive anyway.

Maybe someone else can come up with some feasible trick, but I can't think of any.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it requires data structure and algorithm.
A pure function similar to mapping feature should be written so that it can be called within the original pure function instead of mapping

Answer (score 0):

Simple code example, but if you rewrite to assembly you got cheaper method.
if your it will be goal, you can apply test-driven development methodology and use **hardhat-gas-reporter** package.

```
function checkDuplicates(uint[] memory arr) public pure returns(bool) {
    uint i;
    bool[] memory tmp;

    for(;i<arr.length;) {
        if(tmp[arr[i]] == true) {
            return false;
        }
        tmp[arr[i]] = true;

        unchecked {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I hope I helped a little bit :)

Comment: This doesn't really work. You would need `tmp` to be a mapping, not array (moreover without size), which doesn't exist beside storage (high gas cost)